# Set Lyrics in MP3 ID3v2 Tag

Tags: java, android, mp3, id3v2

I want to write lyrics to an mp3 in an Android application.I have found a java library for reading `mp3` files and reading/manipulating the ID3 tags (ID3v1 and ID3v2.2 through ID3v2.4), named [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic).

I modified `mp3agic` to write the lyric tag of the ID3v2 tag, writing the tag: `USLT`. Found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_Frame_Specification_.28Version_2.3.29)

In a sample Android app I modify the artist, album, title, genre, lyrics, and comment of an MP3. All tags are modified correct except for the lyrics. `PowerAMP` is used to verify the modified `MP3` file and `PowerAMP` cannot find the lyrics in the MP3.

If anyone is familiar with this library here is my modified code from AbstractID3v2Tag.java:

```
//define lyric tag for id3v2
public static final String ID_TEXT_LYRICS = "USLT";

//get the lyrics from the tag
public String getLyrics() {
    ID3v2TextFrameData frameData;
    if (obseleteFormat) return null;
    else frameData = extractTextFrameData(ID_TEXT_LYRICS);
    if (frameData != null && frameData.getText() != null) 
        return frameData.getText().toString();
    return null;
}

//set the lyrics in the tag
public void setLyrics(String lyrics) {
    if (lyrics != null && lyrics.length() > 0) {
        invalidateDataLength();
        ID3v2TextFrameData frameData = new ID3v2TextFrameData(useFrameUnsynchronisation(), new EncodedText(lyrics));
        addFrame(createFrame(ID_TEXT_LYRICS, frameData.toBytes()), true);
    }
}
```

I set the lyrics on an `MP3` with a program in Windows and read the `USLT` tag with my app and `getLyrics()` returned the string `eng`.  `PowerAMP` did find these lyrics set by the Windows program.

I have searched and found many posts pointing to MP3 ID3 tag modifier library's, that's where I found mp3agic. Which is the only library I could easily modify to incorporate changing of lyrics.

One library I found was [MyID3_for_Android](https://sites.google.com/site/eternalsandbox/myid3-for-android) which did not have a method to modify lyrics.

I am looking for guidance on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the official ID3 specification at http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames:

```
Header for 'Unsynchronised lyrics/text transcription', ID: "USLT":
    Text encoding        $xx
    Language             $xx xx xx
    Content descriptor   (text string according to encoding) $00 (00)
    Lyrics/text          (full text string according to encoding)
```

So, the USLT frame is not just a text frame, which is how you're trying to parse it. By comparison, a text frame looks like this:

```
Header for 'Text information frame', ID: "T000" - "TZZZ" excluding "TXXX":
    Text encoding                $xx
    Information                  (text string(s) according to encoding)
```

Note the extra fields in the USLT frame. You'll need a custom frame class (say, ID3v2LyricsFrameData).

The USLT frame is however very similar to a comment frame (COMM), so you can probably re-use some of this code. Perhaps create a superclass that ID3v2CommentFrameData and ID3v2LyricsFrameData both extend.

Comment: Your suggestion was spot on.